# Create a constructor for a shared_ptr<MyClass>

Tags: c++, typedef, smart-pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestX {
public:
    int i;
    TestX(int inp1) : i(inp1){}

};
using Test = std::shared_ptr<TestX>;

int main()
{
    Test a(4);
    std::cout << a->i << std::endl;
}
```

I wanted to hide away that I am using a shared pointer, and make it look like I have just a regular class. The reason is that it is essential that my objects are never copied, but I still want the users to be able to create a vector with `{obj1, obj2}`. Is there a way to initialize a Test object as if there was a constructor, or do I have to use `make_shared` to initialize it?

Comment: Like? `auto Test(int val) { return std::make_shared<TestX>(val); }` and then `auto a = Test(4);` But I'm not sure what you mean by 'hide'.

Comment: I believe adding `
auto Test(int val) { return std::make_shared<TestX>(val); }` will collide with my typedef? Which means any function that accepts Test as an argument, would have to write out `std::shared_ptr<TestX>` instead.

Comment: Then call the function `TestMake`?

Comment: There is also [std::enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) But I'm not sure what you are looking for...

Comment: So, I've got to ask, Why a shared pointer if no one can use it?

Comment: Doing `std::vector{a, b};` in the accepted anwser makes sure that if someone passes the vector to a function, and that function changes `i`, this will be reflected in the original `a`. But if I didn't have a shared pointer, it would instead copy the variable and the changes would not be reflected.

Comment: So, you pass by reference and it will get changed. But if you don't need to keep a pointer, just add that `&int` to your `TestX` class

Comment: @lakeweb Could you please elaborate? I did https://pastebin.com/aUByz8ZE

But the output is 0.

Comment: Hi dockynodyerror, I'm shutting down for the night but I will in the morning. And no, you don't want `int& i;` in your class. You want to expose it with a method.

Comment: So, to be clear, and I'm going with @asmmo's answer as you marked it. You want to expose the int member for use? Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e7e97d21f590a1a) fit what you are looking for?

Comment: @lakeweb The point is that http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/906d0a2d93833aa6 I would like it to print 2 4 6 2. The accepted answer accomplished this with the shared_ptr, as the reference to TextX will be copied, and not the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to wrap a `std::shared_ptr`, as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct TestX {
    int i;
    TestX(int inp1) : i(inp1){}
    TestX(TestX const &) = delete;

};

struct Test {
    std::shared_ptr<TestX>test;
    Test(int inp1) : test{std::make_shared<TestX>(inp1)}{}
    int& get_i (){
        return test -> i;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Test a(4);
    Test b(1);
    auto v = std::vector{a, b};
    std::cout << a.get_i() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the feeling that's what the op is looking for. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @lakeweb What i understood is the op wants to use `shared_ptr` and hide it and this is a perfect way to do that, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, this does look interesting! Could you explain what `TestX(TestX const &) = delete;` does?

Comment: @dockynodyerror deletes the copy constructor or prevents copying the instances from the class.

Comment: Ah thanks! Somehow I believed that this would be `class_name ( const class_name & ) = delete; `, but apparently many ways are valid!

Comment: Ok, it must be what he wanted. But he wrote `{obj1, obj2}` as if he wanted the objects, not the int in the object.

Comment: @lakeweb yes u r right I haven't noticed that it may affect the ctor of the vector. it's better now. thank u.

Comment: @lakeweb I don't know why I answered the question! I feel it's an `xy` problem.

Comment: @asmmo, I was smelling the xy problem for a while! So, see my last question to the op.

Answer (score 0):

you can also derive from shared_ptr<TestX>

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class TestX {
public:
    int i;
    TestX(int inp1) : i(inp1){}
};

struct Test : std::shared_ptr<TestX>{
   Test( int x) : std::shared_ptr<TestX>{std::make_shared<TestX>(x)}{}
};

int main()
{
    Test a(4);
    std::cout << a->i << std::endl;

    Test b(1);
    auto v = std::vector{a, b};
}
```